# How does Keras 1d convolution layer work with word embeddings - text classification problem? (Filters, kernel size, and all hyperparameter)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, word-embedding

I am currently developing a text classification tool using Keras. It works (it works fine and I got up to 98.7 validation accuracy) but I can't wrap my head around about how exactly 1D-convolution layer works with text data.

What hyper-parameters should I use?

I have the following sentences (input data):

- Maximum words in the sentence: 951 (if it's less - the paddings are added)
- Vocabulary size: ~32000
- Amount of sentences (for training): 9800
- embedding_vecor_length: 32 (how many relations each word has in word embeddings)
- batch_size: 37 (it doesn't matter for this question)
- Number of labels (classes): 4

It's a very simple model (I have made more complicated structures but, strangely it works better - even without using LSTM):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(labels_count, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

My main question is: What hyper-parameters should I use for Conv1D layer?

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))
```

If I have following input data:

- Max word count: 951
- Word-embeddings dimension: 32

Does it mean that `filters=32` will only scan first 32 words completely discarding the rest (with `kernel_size=2`)? And I should set filters to 951 (max amount of words in the sentence)?

Examples on images:

So for instance this is an input data: http://joxi.ru/krDGDBBiEByPJA

It's the first step of a convoulution layer (stride 2): http://joxi.ru/Y2LB099C9dWkOr

It's the second step (stride 2): http://joxi.ru/brRG699iJ3Ra1m

And if `filters = 32`, layer repeats it 32 times? Am I correct?
So I won't get to say 156-th word in the sentence, and thus this information will be lost?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would try to explain how 1D-Convolution is applied on a sequence data. I just use the example of a sentence consisting of words but obviously it is not specific to text data and it is the same with other sequence data and timeseries.

Suppose we have a sentence consisting of `m` words where each word has been represented using word embeddings:

[image: Input data]

Now we would like to apply a 1D convolution layer consisting of `n` different filters with kernel size of `k` on this data. To do so, sliding windows of length `k` are extracted from the data and then each filter is applied on each of those extracted windows. Here is an illustration of what happens (here I have assumed `k=3` and removed the bias parameter of each filter for simplicity):

[image: Filters]

As you can see in the figure above, the response of each filter is equivalent to the result of its convolution (i.e. element-wise multiplication and then summing all the results) with the extracted window of length `k` (i.e. `i`-th to `(i+k-1)`-th words in the given sentence). Further, note that each filter has the same number of channels as the number of features (i.e. word-embeddings dimension) of the training sample (hence performing convolution, i.e. element-wise multiplication, is possible). Essentially, each filter is detecting the presence of a particular feature of pattern in a **local** window of training data (e.g. whether a couple of specific words exist in this window or not). After all the filters have been applied on all the windows of length `k` we would have an output of like this which is the result of convolution:

[image: filters response]

As you can see, there are `m-k+1` windows in the figure since we have assumed that the `padding='valid'` and `stride=1` (default behavior of [`Conv1D`](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv1d) layer in Keras). The `stride` argument determines how much the window should slide (i.e. shift) to extract the next window (e.g. in our example above, a stride of 2 would extract windows of words: `(1,2,3), (3,4,5), (5,6,7), ...` instead). The `padding` argument determines whether the window should entirely consists of the words in training sample or there should be paddings at the beginning and at the end; this way, the convolution response may have the same length (i.e. `m` and not `m-k+1`) as the training sample (e.g. in our example above, `padding='same'` would extract windows of words: `(PAD,1,2), (1,2,3), (2,3,4), ..., (m-2,m-1,m), (m-1,m, PAD)`).

You can verify some of the things I mentioned using Keras:

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers

n = 32  # number of filters
m = 20  # number of words in a sentence
k = 3   # kernel size of filters
emb_dim = 100  # embedding dimension

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv1D(n, k, input_shape=(m, emb_dim)))

model.summary()
```

Model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 18, 32)            9632      
=================================================================
Total params: 9,632
Trainable params: 9,632
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

As you can see the output of convolution layer has a shape of `(m-k+1,n) = (18, 32)` and the number of parameters (i.e. filters weights) in the convolution layer is equal to: `num_filters * (kernel_size * n_features) + one_bias_per_filter = n * (k * emb_dim) + n = 32 * (3 * 100) + 32 = 9632`.

Comment: could you please also explain the concept of parameter sharing via this example?

Comment: @vampiretap The parameter sharing of convolution layer is evident from the explanations and figures in the answer: each filter (i.e. **same set of parameters**) is applied on **all the windows** of given data, which means the parameters are shared across the data.

Comment: Just a quick question: How a window of shape (3 X emb_dim) gets dot product with a filter of same shape results in a single value (as per your second figure)? I mean how a `window 1` [dot] `filter 1` gives a scaler to put on 0,0 cell of your second figure? Could you please help me understand that?

Comment: @NuhilMehdy That's basically what convolution (or correlation) operation means: **sum** of **element-wise** multiplication between two vectors or matrices (or tensors in general). Since we sum all the multiplication results together, we would get a single scalar value as the final result.

Comment: @today Thanks! got it. I was confused by the term Dot Product and was wondering how come it gives a scaler. Seems like Convolution works differently (like you mentioned).

Comment: @NuhilMehdy Yeah, you are right. I should not have used the term "dot product" since it may confuse the reader. Instead, using the "convolution" itself along with a short definition (i.e. "element-wise multiplication and then summing all the results") is a better choice. I just edited my answer to reflect that. Thanks!

Comment: @nuhilmehdy A dot product is the sum of element-wise products (multiplication). Each time the window slides 1 position the filter outputs a scalar (dot product). Another word for a sliding window  dot product is "cross-correlation". Unfortunately the word "convolution" in signal processing implies that you flip the order of the dimensions in your kernel before doing the multiplication. So the terms cross-correlation and dot product are more correct and unambiguous and well-defined.