# Error when checking target: expected dense_101 to have shape (143, 3) but got array with shape (855, 3)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I have a Keras model like this:

```
model=Sequential()
'''
filters=number of conv kernel
strides=step
'''
model.add(Convolution1D(filters=1000, kernel_size=11,strides=3,
                    input_shape=(train_num,data_dim),padding='same',
                    activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))

model.add(Convolution1D(filters=1000, kernel_size=7, strides=2,        padding='same',
                    activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))

model.add(Convolution1D(filters=1000, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same',
                    activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))


model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))  
model.add(Dropout(0.3))  

model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))  
model.add(Dropout(0.3))  

model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))  
model.add(Dropout(0.3))  

model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))  
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='sgd',metrics=['accuracy'])  
model.summary()


print("training starts.....")
model.fit(trX,trY,epochs=30,batch_size=100)


accuracy=model.evaluate(teX,teYY,batch_size=100)
predict_y = model.predict(teX)
print('\nTest accuracy:',accuracy[1])
#predict=model.predict(teY,batch_size=30)

save_model(model,'my_model_com3hl')
```

My input data shape is `(1,855,1000)`. That means I have 855 samples and every sample has 1000 dim. But when I was training, the sample dim of output shape decreased like this and the following error occured:

> Error when checking target: expected dense_101 to have shape (143, 3)
>   but got array with shape (855, 3)

Here is the model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_50 (Conv1D)           (None, 285, 1000)         11001000  
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_51 (Conv1D)           (None, 143, 1000)         7001000   
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_52 (Conv1D)           (None, 143, 1000)         3001000   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_98 (Dense)             (None, 143, 128)          128128    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_71 (Dropout)         (None, 143, 128)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_99 (Dense)             (None, 143, 128)          16512     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_72 (Dropout)         (None, 143, 128)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_100 (Dense)            (None, 143, 128)          16512     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_73 (Dropout)         (None, 143, 128)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_101 (Dense)            (None, 143, 3)            387       
=================================================================
```

Comment: Reshape your training data to `(855, 1000, 1)`, i.e. `trX = np.reshape(trX, (855, 1000, 1))` and correct the input shape argument: `input_shape=(data_dim, 1)`. (BTW, `np` is numpy: `import numpy as np`).

Comment: Thank you for your modification and help, I'm new to this platform. I reshaped the data and corrected the input shape argument, however, i get a new error that seems still caused by the data shape. Now the error is :
[Error when checking target: expected dense_113 to have shape (167, 3) but got array with shape (3, 1) ].

Comment: @today And my model summary has similar problem as before.

Comment: What is the `teYY.shape`? Pleas clarify what is the input shape and output shape of the model? For example, an input sample has a shape of `(1000,1)` and the output is `(3,)`, i.e. you are doing classification, right?

Comment: Yes, it's a three classes classification problem.  I have 855 training samples and 214 test samples. Both samples have 1000 dimension characters. The labels are in one-hot mode. The shape of `trX`, `trY`, `teX`, `teYY` are `(855,1000,1)`,`(214,3,1)`,`(214,1000,1)`,`(214,3,1)`,respectively. And the error still occured at `model.fit()` step, I don't think teYY leads to the error. Maybe `trY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment:

> Yes, it's a three classes classification problem. I have 855 training
>   samples and 214 test samples. Both samples have 1000 dimension
>   characters. The labels are in one-hot mode. The shape of trX, trY,
>   teX, teYY are
>   (855,1000,1),(214,3,1),(214,1000,1),(214,3,1),respectively...

each sample with a shape of `(1000,1)` is classified as one of three classes. So, to make the output shape of the network compatible with the labels shape, you should use a [`Flatten`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#flatten) layer right before the first dense layer:

```
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))  
model.add(Dropout(0.3)) 

# ... the rest
```

Now the output shape of the model would be `(None,3)` and this is exactly what we need. You may also need to remove the last axis of labels to make them have a shape of `(*,3)` (and not `(*,3,*)`):

```
trY = np.squeeze(trY, axis=2)
teYY = np.squeeze(teYY, axis=2)
```

Further, don't forget my comment about `input_shape`. You need to fix it as well.

---

As a side note, having 1000 thousand filters in each of the three convolution layers (considering that the length of each training sample is 1000) may be (very) inefficient. Instead, using 32, 64, 128 or 256 filters might be a better option (and increase the number of filters as go deeper in the model). Further, if you would like to know more about how 1D-convolution works [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353721/2099607) might help you.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much I ignore the the role of flatten layer. You really help me a lot! Thank you again!