# How to reshape data for 1D convolutional layer in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm getting confused by the documentation and examples for a `conv1D`.  I know what I want to do, but I'd appreciate a bit of help with how I should reshape my data for keras to implement what I've got in mind.

My data are daily measurements of single variables, related to a single annual outcome.  They look kind of like this:

```
   v1t1 v1t2 v1t3 v1t4 v2t1 v2t2 v2t3 v2t4 v3t1 v3t2 v3t3 v3t4
1     5    4    6    5    3    4    6    3    5    4    4    5
2     5    3    3    4    6    5    5    5    5    4    8    6
3     5    4    8    4    4    4    6    5    7    3    7    5
4     5    5    6    6    5    6    6    4    7    7    4    2
5     8    5    5    6    3    4    3    3    4    5    4    5
6     5    4    4    3    8    5    7    6    5    7    6    4
7     5    6    7    4    7    4    3    4    5    7    4    3
8     5    6    6    4    7    7    4    6    7    3    5    5
9     2    4    5    4    6    4    6    7    6    5    2    7
10    2    7    4    2    3    2    2    3    5    4    6    4
```

So, a node one level up from the input data should be a function of the values of `v1`, `v2`, and `v3`, trained on observations from adjacent periods of time -- so if the stride was 2, then the first node would be trained on `v1t1`, `v2t1`, `v3t1`, `v1t2`, `v2t2`, and `v3t2`

What shape would keras expect for this?

Comment: Keras Conv1D requires `(batch, steps, channels)` if `data_format = "channels_last"`. In this case, `(10, 4, 3)` .  "channels_last" is the default in Keras.

Comment: @KotaMori thanks!  So a 3d array with one variable in each matrix, with the time dimension along the y axis and the number of observations on the x axis?

Comment: @generic_user [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353721/2099607) might help you to better understand Conv1D layer and how its input data should be formatted.