# Correct Shape for Keras - Non Image 1D CNN

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to cement my understanding of using a 1D for text and time series classification using Keras / TF. Can anyone confirm or correct my understanding?

**Text Embedding**

In the example using a 1D cnn with an embedding [keras example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_cnn.py), the input going into the 1D CNN is (samples, vocab size, embedding size). Here I think of this as for a given sample/observation, the input is a matrix where the rows are the terms/words and the columns are the series that describe the words (i.e. the embedding representation). Concretely, lets say there are 10 words and the embeddings are of length 5. So each sample is 10 x 5.

Then, each kernel is  x 5. Here, filter length is a misnomer it seems because it describes the height of the kernel. The length of the kernel is always the same size as the embeddings (columns of the input matrix for each sample).

The kernel moves down the input matrix and thus looks at groups of contiguous words.

**Is this Correct?**

**Time Series**

In this setup, the input for each sample/observation is also a matrix, but where the columns are the series and the rows are the values of the series (cell 1,1 is the first temporal value of the first series. The cell 3,8 is the 3rd temporal value of the 8th series etc.). As a concrete example, say there are 36 values of 10 series. The input matrix for each sample/observation is 36 x 10.

Then, given a kernel that is  x 10 (where 10 is fixed to the number of series) the kernel moves down the matrix, where unlike the text embedding, where word representations are combined, here it combines the temporal representation of the series. By this I mean if the kernel is 2 x 10 and the series are measured per day, it combines the first 2 days of all 10 series at once and then continues...

**Is this correct?**

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353721/2099607) might give you a visual overview of how 1D convolution works.

Comment: I did not find that response. Thanks for the reference! It looks like my understanding of the text embedding above matches your answer correct?

Comment: In the time series case it is exactly the same? In other words I think your answer says my uunderstanding is correct in both cases?

Comment: Yes, both are correct. Just a minor note: you may look at each column as a timeseries or, in a different way, sometimes a combination of multiple columns (or even all the columns) is regarded as one timeseries, which is referred to as multi-variate timeseries (i.e. a timeseries with multiple variables per timestep).

Comment: I think of each column as a measurement where the rows are a time step ( e.g. a day ) and the columns are series like number of page views, amount spent on a type of product, number of clicks on links etc, In this case, the sample / observation ( axis 0) might be a customer. What is the other type you are imagining.

Comment: I mean any measurement which is described [with more than one variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/342821/114422). Of course, you can regard each of those variables as an independent timeseries (i.e. multiple uni-variate timeseries). As I mentioned it is a minor terminology (and somehow opinion-based) thing. Nothing important...

Comment: Got it, thanks for confirming my understanding!