# 2D-CNN model with keras on one-hot-encoding dataset

Tags: python-2.7, keras, one-hot-encoding

How to design a keras 2D-CNN model with one-hot-encoded genomic sequence data?

I have almost 50,000 genomic sequences of fixed lengths. I am trying to model a 2D-CNN for a 2 class classification problem. First I converted the sequences using one-hot-encoding. Thus each sample (sequence) becomes a `4 x 200` matrix. From here I assumed from numerous `mnist` examples available in `Github`, I can treat this matrix as any other image matrix. Thus I coded similar to the code given in `mnist` examples. Here is my code

```
X_train = sample_matrices[0:N1]
X_valid = sample_matrices[N1:N2]
X_test = sample_matrices[N2:num_sample]

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], row, col, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], row, col, 1)
X_valid = X_valid.reshape(X_valid.shape[0], row, col, 1)
input_shape = (row, col, 1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3, 3),
                     activation = 'relu',
                     input_shape = input_shape))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

here `row = 4, col = 200`

I got an error message

`ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for 'conv2d_2/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,2,198,32], [3,3,32,64].`

I am almost certain I am doing something wrong with the `input_shape` but I'm not sure what. Could anyone please help?
Sorry if the question is too naive.

Comment: I am not very familiar with this particular use-case (i.e. genomic data), however this appears to me to be a 1D sequence. So isn't it better to use 1D-convolution instead? For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353721/2099607).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from your second layer (conv2d_2).
You are receiving this error because the first layer (conv2d_1) produces
a matrix of shape `[?,2,198,32]` (batch, rows, cols, channels) and you try
to use a `kernel_size=(3, 3)` (rows, cols)  `padding="valid"`
(default parameter), an overflow occurs.

You can avoid this error by changing the default setting of `padding="valid"` to `padding="same"`
inside the Conv2D constructor as shown in the documentations https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/
or by changing `kernel_size=(1, 3)` (rows, cols) for conv2d_2.

By changing the padding you allow the input shape to be padded with zero (if necessary).
e.g:

- "VALID" = Without padding:

  ```
     Inputs:  1  2  ?  <-- Overflow
             |_______|

     Output rows shape: ceil((rows_in - kernel_size[0] + 1) / strides[0]) = 0
     Output cols shape: ceil((cols_in - kernel_size[1] + 1) / strides[1])
  ```
- "SAME" = With zero padding:

  ```
                  | pad
     Inputs:  1  2| 0  0
             |_______|
                |_______|

     Output rows shape: ceil(rows_in / strides[0]) = 2
     Output cols shape: ceil(cols_in / strides[1])
  ```

In this example:

- input  rows = 2 (As the number of rows the conv2d_1 output)
- kernel_size = 3