# How to add convolutional layer to Keras model?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

There is data that contains A, B, C. C value should be predicted from A and B values.

[image]

The data was split and scaled.

[image]

Model without convolutional layer.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D

features_count = len(X_train.columns)

model = Sequential([
    Dense(64, input_shape=(features_count,)),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(32),
    Activation('softmax'),
    Dense(1),
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='mse')
model.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=1)
```

**Result**: 1.0033315420150757

Added Conv1D:

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(features_count,)),
    Dense(64),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(32),
    Activation('softmax'),
    Dense(1),
])
```

**Result**: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_3: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

```
input_shape=(features_count,)
```

was replaced by

```
input_shape=(features_count,1)
```

**Result**: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_4_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (3, 2)

What is wrong with adding convolutional layer in this way? How to add a convolutional layer to Keras model?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What are these features? Are you sure convolution makes sense here (I doubt it)? Why set a filter size of 5 if there are only 2 features?

Comment: I have a 100Mb dataset with 750 features - here I simplified it. As I wrote I need to predict value C from A and B. This is just an example. I am trying to add a convolutional layer to improve MSE. filter size of 5 - okey I will fix it

Comment: Using Conv1D only makes sense if the input data is a sequence, i.e. the order of values is important. Does this apply to your dataset? Or is it the case that each row in your dataset is independent of other rows? If so, then using Conv1D or RNN does not make sense.

Comment: @today yes it is daily stock closing stock price. What I am trying to do is predicting stock price from other stock prices which has enough correlation with selected ticker.

Comment: All right then, you first need to convert your whole data into small sequences of shape `(seq_len, num_features)` such that the whole data would look like `(num_samples, seq_len, num_features)`. For that, you can get help from [`TimeSeriesGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#timeseriesgenerator) in Keras.

Comment: Further, if it's not clear for you how 1D-convolution works, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353721/2099607) might help you to better understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conv1D expects a 2D data, for it can apply convolution for first dimension along the second dimension. So, your input data must have shape (Batch size, 1, 2). But, Dense layer need 1D, so between Conv1D and Dense you need to add a Flatten layer to transform your data in 1D.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D, Activation, Flatten
import numpy as np
X_train = np.array([[-1.0,-1.0], [1.0, -1.0], [1.0,1.0]])
y_train = np.array([[1.0], [-1.0], [0.0]])

X_test = np.array([[1.0,-1.0], [1.0, -1.0]])
y_test = np.array([[1.0], [-1.0]])

features_count = 2

model = Sequential([
    Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(1,features_count)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(64),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(32),
    Activation('softmax'),
    Dense(1),
])

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1])
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='mse')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=1)
```

**Result:** 1.00140380859375

Hope this help you.

Comment: I could not add this layer for 2 weeks. Finally, it is working. Thank you!

Comment: Im glad it helped you!