# How to find input_shape of Convolutional Neural Network when we are trying to fit the data from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a pandas dataframe X_train with 321 samples and 43 features. Also, there are 18 different classes in y_train.

[image]

strong textI want to train a CNN over my data, but I am having trouble to give the input shape in case of pandas dataframe.

```
X.shape, y.shape
((321, 43), (321,))

X = np.array(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0, stratify = y)

X_train.shape, X_test.shape
((256, 43), (65, 43))

inputs = np.concatenate((X_train, X_test), axis=0)
targets = np.concatenate((y_train, y_test), axis=0)

inputs.shape, targets.shape
((321, 43), (321,))
```

In the first layer of my model, I am having trouble with input_shape.

I am new to CNN and all the tutorials have used image and they are just passing in the height, width and channel as the parameter of input_shape.

```
fold_no = 1
for train, test in kfold.split(inputs, targets):

    model = Sequential()
    **model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(???)))**
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(18, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 0.001), 
                                 loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                                 metrics = ['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(inputs[train], targets[train], batch_size=5, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1)

    scores = model.evaluate(inputs[test], targets[test], verbose=0)
    
    fold_no = fold_no + 1
```

I am having trouble with input_shape in the first layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(???)))
```

I tried to set the input shape like the following format:

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(None, train.shape[1])))
```

But I got the following error:

[image]

I also tried in this way:

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(321, 43)))
```

Then I got the following error:
[image]

I also tried the following format:

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(None, 43)))
```

Then I got the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Conv1D [takes a 3D shape as an input](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/), but the 1st dimension is the batch size, so you can ignore it for `input_shape`. The other 2 dimensions are (steps, input_dim).

When dealing with numeric or text data, the two dimensions are usually (a) how many sequential rows you want your CNN layer to process at once, (b) how many features are in the row. If your data is naturally segmented into specific lengths (maybe 24, for hours in a day, or 3 words in a trigram), you'll want to specifically set the `steps` dimension. It will also affect your output shape, which will be `(steps-kernel_size+1, filters)`. Try using some different shapes and look at the model summary to see how they change.

But as the documentation says, you can also use `None` as your steps, e.g. `(None, 128) for variable-length sequences of 128-dimensional vectors`.

So basically, I'd suggest this, where `inputs[train].shape[1]` should be 43 for you:

```
input_shape=(None, inputs[train].shape[1])
```

You could also try the full length of your dataset, e.g. (321, 43):

```
input_shape=inputs[train].shape
```

Take a look at [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353721/3061852) and also [this article](https://missinglink.ai/guides/keras/keras-conv1d-working-1d-convolutional-neural-networks-keras/) for a good visual intuition of how Conv1D works on numeric/text input.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I updated my post, tried to adjust the input shape as you mentioned, but found an error.
I attached the error I got to my post.
Could you please guide me how I can fix it?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mixed up your variables. Please try again. You could also try `(None, 43)`?

Comment: I also tried input_shape=(None, 43), but it doesn't work. I attached the Traceback report to my post.

Answer (score 0):

tensor =1D sample or data point how many numbers or features = and number of samples.

In this case

sample1 or vector=[x0,x1,x2,...,ystando], total amount of samples are:321 and total features=31,it will have input_shape=(321,43) of the tensor